# Incrementing a for loop over a List of java objects

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a list of objects called employee() and I used emp as my object. I want to increment over employees and print the name of all the objects. I really lost on how to do this. Thanks.

```
for( emp ;  ;employees())
        {
        System.out.println(emp.name);
        }
```

Comment: [Don't come back until you've read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Yeah, it is. I didn't know the name of the "for each" loop. The reason I can see for keeping it is that for for other people that don't know what "for each" loop is, they might be able to find their answer through this thread.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I did read that. It wasn't too helpful for iterating over objects from a newb's point of view. I was mixing things up as Woody righted me.

Comment: @AwayFromMyDesk You aren't serious... The last three paragraphs of the link is exactly about that, with examples and everything. All I had to do was type `java for loop` into google.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, when the example uses int's it's more clear from somebodies point of view that has never touched OOP before. Using my own objects made it a little more foggy. Obviously, I set up the for loop (which I also did after typing it into Google) but was putting the parameters in incorrectly.

Comment: I don't know what else I can say. `java for loop objects` in Google brings up all sorts of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `foreach()`

```
for(Employee employee : employees())
{
System.out.println(employee.name);
}
```